# How to edit or write file in onlyoffice using ReactJS or NodeJS?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, onlyoffice

Is it possible to edit or write in file using ReactJS (frontend) or NodeJS (backend) ?

This is my current Integration of onlyOffice in ReactJS using @onlyoffice/document-editor-react

```
  <div className="h-[94vh] w-full ">
      <DocumentEditor
        style={{ height: "100%" }}
        id="docxEditor"
        documentServerUrl="<document_server_url>"
        config={{
          document: {
            fileType: "docx",
            "title": "sample4.docx",,
            url: "<document_URL>",
            key: "<key>",
          },

          documentType: "word",
          editorConfig: {
            callbackUrl: "<my-url>"
          },
        }}
        events_onDocumentReady={onDocumentReady}
        onLoadComponentError={onLoadComponentError}
      />
   </div>
```